# Play 2.3 WS keystore configuration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, play-ws

I have a p12 keystore having a password e.g. [keystore password] and the private key inside is also encrypted with another password e.g [private key password]. How do I configure it for client authentication in play ws. I tried the below in application.conf but not working.

```
# WS config
ws.ssl {
  keyManager = {
    stores = [
      { type: "PKCS12",
        path: "keystore.p12",
        password: "[keystore password]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with and absolute path.

Comment: also tried with absolute path, same problem